# tryCatch to assign data frame to global environment if it isn't loaded or doesn't exist

Tags: r

I have data saved locally:

```
elo.data <- data.frame(player = c("M1", "A1"), rating = c(2000, 2000))
elo.data$time <- rep(Sys.time(),length(elo.data$player))
write.csv(elo.data, file = "elo.data.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

But sometimes it doesn't exist. So I'd like to create an empty data frame with tryCatch but I am getting the following error when elo.data isn't loaded or isn't stored locally:

```
# reset function
elo.reset <- function() {
    elo.data <- data.frame(
        player = character(),
        rating = character(),
        time = as.POSIXct(character()),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
    assign("elo.data", elo.data, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}

# load data functon
elo.load <- function() {
    elo.data <- read.csv("elo.data.csv", header = TRUE)
    assign("elo.data", elo.data, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}

# load data
tryCatch(elo.load(), error = elo.reset())
```

> Error in tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]]) :
>   attempt to apply non-function In addition: Warning message: In
>   file(file, "rt") :   cannot open file 'elo.data.csv': No such file or
>   directory

This is my first time using tryCatch.

Comment: Rather than having `reset` and `load` functions that alter the global environment, I would do something like `if(!exists("elo.data")) elo.data = data.frame(...)` or `elo.data = read.csv("elo.data.csv", ...)`. Altering the global environment is generally frowned upon. Having your functions `return()` an object and assigning it is standard.

Comment: The error function of `tryCatch` requires one parameter, your `elo.reset` function has no parameter. Therefore it does not work. See help via `tryCatch`. That the handler functions require a parameter is hidden in the long help text in the sentence **"the handler is called with the condition as its argument"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no need to use try catch if it is a matter of csv file. This should be preferred way, assuming you want to save to `.GlobalEnv` which isn't best practice. Otherwise just return `elo.data` and assign it to variable when calling your function.

```
elo.load <- function() {
    elo.data <- if (file.exists("elo.data.csv")) {
        read.csv("elo.data.csv", header = TRUE)
    } else {
        data.frame(
            player = character(),
            rating = character(),
            time = as.POSIXct(character()),
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE
        )
    }
    assign("elo.data", elo.data, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
elo.load()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your `reset` function in the error function.

```
tryCatch(elo.load(), error = function(e) elo.reset())
```

This will throw a warning message but still get your `elo.reset()` executed, if you want to suppress the warning message, you can use `suppressWarnings()`:

```
tryCatch(suppressWarnings(elo.load()), error = function(e) elo.reset())
```